# SpriteKit 3 nodes?

Tags: sprite-kit

Recently when using Xcode 7.2 with SpritKit I have noticed that when running the boilerplate "New project" Sprite Kit app it says "nodes:3 60.0 fps" on the bottom-right corner of the device. In the past when running this it would read only 1 node... Does anybody know what changed? or is it just me seeing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is strange.  If you query self.children.count, it will still print out 1, but it looks like the label is being counted twice via the node counter.  If you don't add the label, it says 1 node.

I wonder if the label is being handled similar to the SKShapeNode under the hood.  It counts that as two nodes as well: One for the border and one for the fill.

Comment: Thanks @Trent, after deleting everything from both my SKS view and from the code, I've reached the conclusion that the "Scene" itself is being counted as a node. This isn't the way Xcode used to behave so it surprised me to see the change. If anyone has more info that would be awesome.